# Trying to find Drivers for RTL8188EUS in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless

First, to say that it is an old desktop pc, with a Pentium D 925, and 2 GB of RAM, it did not go well with Windows 7, so I saw on the internet that a way for it to have better performance was to install Linux on it. In my case I chose a Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and a Kernel 4.15.0-176-generic.

Right now I am looking for a page where I can find the drivers, because I have found pages on GitHub and on this same page, that do not work for me, because they are or the installation aborts itself, pausing the terminal and doing nothing.

Thanks for your patience, I'm new to this and trying to understand new things ;).

Comment: What is the question? What have you done and why?

Comment: I don't know how to install the drivers, I just follow a youtube video and didn't work

Comment: Why would you install 18.04 at this time? It is over 4 years old and only has 6 months of support left. In particular, newer hardware might not be supported without swapping to the HWE kernel. I suggest installing a newer release. If you still have problems, I suggest searching RTL8188 here for help. If you *still* need help, please add *reproducible* details about your attempts and the problem you are facing. This means the exact actions you're taking and the exact behavior of your device as it's presented to you. Include verbatim all error messages, for example.

Comment: I edited the text with more information, thanks

Comment: "*I have found pages on GitHub and on this same page, that do not work for me, because they are or the installation aborts itself*" - these details are not reproducible. Please add exact details if you'd like more help figuring this out. However I still suggest that you install a newer release. Try Lubuntu 22.04 instead.

Comment: Well, then I'll try to install version 22.04, any news I'll let you know.